# Cannot remove a directory with bad name, created accidentally by Qt in Windows 10

Tags: windows, qt, qdir

I've created a directory using `QDir` but the given name had two dots in the end, Qt created this directory although its bad naming, and now my windows 10 OS cannot operate on this invalid directory.

I cannot do any operation on it.
I've done these:

- run `chkdsk` with fixing flags, ...
- run check disk utility in drive properties
- trying to remove it from command line in cmd and powershell
- trying to delete the directory using `QDir`

What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RemoveDirectoryW(L"\\\\?\\C:\\full\\path\\to\\dir..");
```

Explanation: besides enabling the long path handling [as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-removedirectoryw), the `\\?\` prefix bypasses Win32 path processing, passing the path directly to NT API, so it would go directly to NT kernel.

Make sure you use `RemoveDirectoryW`, not `RemoveDirectoryA`, a fully qualified path, and backwards slashes `'\\'` (not `/`). Due to C++ esaping in string literals, `\\?\C:\path` becomes `"\\\\?\\C:\\path"`.